# Effective way of checking if all eigenvalues of a matrix are integers

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given A matrix with integer entries, it should be checked if all its eigenvalues
 are integers.

Of course, the characteristic polynomial could be calculated, but is there any
 faster (or easier) method ?

Another possibility would be : Search a bound for the eigenvalues and check for
 each possible integer n, if $A-nI$ is invertible. But this is also cumbersome and another problem is that multiple eigenvalues may not be detected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any integer polynomial, we can write down the companion matrix.  For any integer matrix, we can quickly calculate the characteristic polynomial.

So your question is essentially equivalent to (and at least as hard as) the question: How can we tell if all the roots of a polynomial are integers?

I think that the best method here would be the rational root test.  As a corollary, we only need to check integer factors of the determinant.

Note that, if you want to detect multiple roots, you can take the $d$-th power of $A-nI$ (where $d$ is the dimension) and find the dimension of the kernel.  But this is unlikely to be faster than just factoring the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @Peter No, you *can* avoid it: the possible integer eigenvalues are the (positive and negative) divisors of the determinant. Verifying if a divisor of the determinant  is an eigenvalue is faster than computing the characteristic polynomial, if the matrix is big.  You need the characteristic polynomial if the determinant is zero.

Comment: You can easily use [Yun's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_polynomial#Yun.27s_algorithm) to detect and isolate repeated factors of a polynomial.